# Embed HTML in XML

Tags: android, xml

I'm creating a news app for android where news data transfered to clients using xml. The problem is how can i embed news content inside xml ? News content contains html tag. Here is part of my xml data

```
<title>xxx</title>
<date>xx</date>
<content>html here</content>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to insert HTML content in XML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412395/is-it-possible-to-insert-html-content-in-xml-document)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the `CDATA`-Tag:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: Thanx for the answer, i'll make a try ;)