# Convert html to xml using java

Tags: java, html, xml, jtidy

Can any one suggest me a best approach for converting html to xml using java
Is there any API available for that?
The html also might contain javascript code

I have tried below code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.jdom.JDOMException;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter;
import java.io.IOException;

class HTML2XML {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JDOMException {
    InputStream isInHtml = null;
    URL url = null;
    URLConnection connection = null;
    DataInputStream disInHtml = null;
    FileOutputStream fosOutHtml = null;
    FileWriter fwOutXml = null;
    FileReader frInHtml = null;
    BufferedWriter bwOutXml = null;
    BufferedReader brInHtml = null;
    try {
        // url = new URL("www.climb.co.jp");
        // connection = url.openConnection();
        // isInHtml = connection.getInputStream();

        frInHtml = new FileReader("D:\\Second.html");
        brInHtml = new BufferedReader(frInHtml);
        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder(
                "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser", false);
        org.jdom.Document jdomDocument = saxBuilder.build(brInHtml);

        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
        org.jdom.output.Format newFormat = outputter.getFormat();
        String encoding = "iso-8859-2";
        newFormat.setEncoding(encoding);
        outputter.setFormat(newFormat);

        try {
            outputter.output(jdomDocument, System.out);
            fwOutXml = new FileWriter("D:\\Second.xml");
            bwOutXml = new BufferedWriter(fwOutXml);
            outputter.output(jdomDocument, bwOutXml);
            System.out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        System.out.flush();
        try {
            isInHtml.close();
            disInHtml.close();
            fosOutHtml.flush();
            fosOutHtml.getFD().sync();
            fosOutHtml.close();
            fwOutXml.flush();
            fwOutXml.close();
            bwOutXml.close();
        } catch (Exception w) {

        }
    }
}
}
```

But its not working as expected

Comment: Do you mean XHTML? And what about this Javascript code, what do you want to do with that?

Comment: I have to convert normal html file to xml

Comment: Do you need to convert them *to* XHTML? XHTML is an XML representation of HTML. 'Just' XML can be anything.

Comment: Have you tried http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/?

Comment: Otherwise you can just embed the entire HTML document into a single XML element, as proven [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412395/is-it-possible-to-insert-html-content-in-xml-document). That is probably not what you want, but we need more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [jTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)

> JTidy can be used as a tool for cleaning up malformed and faulty HTML

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse html than rather than converting html to xml you can use html parser.
http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/
http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/doc-files/using.html
I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not the same as XML unless it is conforming XHTML or HTML5 in XML mode.

suggesting to use a HTML parser to read the HTML and transform it to XML – or process it directly.