# Add html tag in Oozie email action

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want to send email from oozie where my body content should be in bold.

workflow.xml:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="email-wf">
    <start to="email_action"/>
        <action name="email_action">
        <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.2">
            <to>test@gmail.com</to>
            <subject>Test mail</subject>
            <body><h1>Email sending with heading level 1</h1></body>
            <content_type>text/html</content_type>
        </email>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Shell action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

job.properties:

```
OOZIE_URL=http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:11000/oozie
nameNode=hdfs://xxx.xxx.xx.x:8020
jobTracker=xxx.xxx.xx.x:8050
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=/tmp/email_workflow.xml
```

So when i was running oozie command it was giving error:

```
Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-type.3.1.2: Element 'body' is a simple type, so it must have no element information item [children].
```

Can some one help me to understand what is missing in above configuration.

Comment: Just to confirm, does it work without the h1 start and end tags?

Comment: Probably have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412395/is-it-possible-to-insert-html-content-in-xml-document

Comment: i modified code from <body><h1>Email sending with heading level 1</h1></body> to <body><![CDATA[<h1>Email sending with color</h1>]]></body> in oozie which is suggested by Dennis Jaheruddin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem probably occurs because you try to use xml like tags within oozie. This confuses oozie as it thinks it is encountering more actual oozie XML.

The solution would be to escape the brackets around your h1 statements.

Either by escaping all relevant characters (where < becomes &lt > becomes &gt), or by [trying to escape the whole line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412395/is-it-possible-to-insert-html-content-in-xml-document) with CDATA.

Comment: I can confirm that escaping all < and > characters solves this issue. It does make the code pretty unreadable and hard to debug.