# Use HTML tags in XML file and display/recognize them later as HTML

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm trying to use HTML Tags inside an xml file which is later used in a view to display the content. My Problem, the HTML tags are passed as plain String eventhough I escaped all necessary Characters appropriately.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>  
    <selfassessment>
        <topic>
            <description>Die &lt;strong&gt; Zweckbestimmung &lt;/strong&gt; ist ein eleme
                Konsequenzen.</description>
            <shortdesc>Zweckbestimmung</shortdesc>
            <question>
                <questiontext>Ihre fest:</questiontext>
                <answer correct="false">Sie habenmung.</answer>
                <answer correct="true"> erreichen sollen.</answer>
                <answer correct="true">Das phyiert.</answer>
                <answer correct="true">Die Chlektuellen eiten.</answer>
                <answer correct="true">Die Beler &quot;Workload&quot;.</answer>
                <answer correct="true">Date.</answer>
                <comment>All  &lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/someLink&quot; class=&quot;button&quot;&gt;Erfahren Sie hier mehr&lt;/a&gt;</comment>
            </question>
        </topic>
     </selfassessment>
```

When displaying it, it doesn't realize the html tags but paste them in plain string.

I have seen all related questions asked here and I tryed using CDATA, without success. Is there something I am missing here? It should be working like this shouldn't it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: (php code involved)

Getting the xml file:

```
function getXmlFile(){
        $xml = null;

        $xmlFile = '/var/www/html/typo3conf/ext/extKeyHere/Resources/Private/XML/data.xml';

        if (file_exists($xmlFile)) {
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
        } else {
         exit("Datei $xmlFile kann nicht geöffnet werden."); 
         //echo "Datei $xmlFile kann nicht geöffnet werden."; 
        } 
        return $xml;
    }
```

And later on I'm using it like this:

```
    function __construct($xmldata) {
        $this->xml = $xmldata;
        $this->calculateResults();
    }

    private function calculateResults() {

        $page = 0;

        //iterating over xml file
        foreach ($this->xml->topic as $thema) {
            $this->topics[$page] = $thema->description;
        and so on.....

        //passing it to the view
        $this->view->assignMultiple(array( 
        'allQuestions' => $allQuestions,
        'questions' => $questions,
        ....
```

Code inside the view:

```
<form method='post' action="{url}">
<h3>{allQuestions.themaDescr}</h3>
<f:for each="{allQuestions.thema.question}" as="question" iteration="i">
   <div class='question'><p><strong>Frage {i.cycle}</strong>: 
    {question.questiontext}</p>
    <f:for each="{question.answer}" as="answer" iteration="ii">
      <div class='answer'><input type='checkbox' name='A{page} 
      {i.cycle}{ii.cycle}'/>
        <div class='subanswer' for='A{page}{i.cycle}{ii.cycle}'> 
         {answer}
        </div>
      </div>
   </f:for>
  </div>
</f:for>
    <input type='hidden' name='page' value='{allQuestions.page}'/>
    <f:if condition="{allQuestions.nextThema}">
        <f:then>
            <button type='submit'>Ergebnisse anzeigen</button>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>`
            <button type='submit'>Nächste Seite</button>
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
</form>
```

No errors, everything works fine except the html tags as I mentioned are displayed as plain text.
By the way this is Typo3, but I don't think it matters except for how I pass the data to the view and display it.

Comment: I don't see any `CDATA` in that code

Comment: You can get example from URL : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412395/is-it-possible-to-insert-html-content-in-xml-document

Comment: @kerbholz maybe I wasn't clear enough. I tryed using CDATA aswell, but it didnt work. But I thought after escaping the html tag chars it should work anyway.

Comment: @Vish I have read exactly that question but it didn't work for me. With the CDATA Section, the HTML tags weren't recognized either and ended up as plain String aswell or was ignored completely

Comment: How are you extracting the HTML from the XML and displaying it? That's the crucial part.

Comment: @BoltClock What do you mean with extracting? I'm simply using the xml file as a data source. I don't extract any HTML from the XML. Could you explain what you mean please? I'm using the simplexml_load_file php function to load the xml and afterwards I just iterate over the simplexml object.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, sorry. Can you add your PHP code to your question?

Comment: @BoltClock I have edited my post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: where is your output fragment of code?

Comment: As long as the HTML is in its escaped form (using the entities) it will never be interpreted as HTML--which is the idea behind escaping.

Comment: @Alex I added the code for the view.

Comment: @Dormilich Thats true, but what is your solution?

Comment: http://php.net/htmlspecialchars-decode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still not clear what is your problem and what is your goal.

Let me try to do some attempt to help you.

First thing - you have data:

```
<description>Die &lt;strong&gt; Zweckbestimmung &lt;/strong&gt; ist ein eleme Konsequenzen.</description>
<comment>All  &lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/someLink&quot; class=&quot;button&quot;&gt;Erfahren Sie hier mehr&lt;/a&gt;</comment>
```

That data portion has html encoded characters. The point is to never mix data with real html or xml.

So when you do:

```
$this->topics[$page] = $thema->description;
```

your value still contain html encoded characters:

```
$this->topics[$page] === `Die &lt;strong&gt; Zweckbestimmung &lt;/strong&gt; ist ein eleme Konsequenzen.`
```

Which is probably kind wrong from your point of view. But to me I don't see any problem yet at this moment.

Then you do:

```
 <div class='question'><p><strong>Frage {i.cycle}</strong>: 
{question.questiontext}</p>
```

Lets simplify and focus only on this part:

```
 <p>{question.questiontext}</p>
```

That one of things which are not clear in your data xml there is no field with name `questiontext`. So lets assume that is `topic->question->comment`.

With your value it means:

```html
<p>All  &lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/someLink&quot; class=&quot;button&quot;&gt;Erfahren Sie hier mehr&lt;/a&gt;</p>
```

And you are not happy to have it like that probably you expect to get:

```html
<p>All <br/><a href="/someLink" class="button">Erfahren Sie hier mehr</a></p>
```

**DANGER** You can do it if you decode html entities back to unencoded characters with `htmlspecialchars_decode` function like:

```
// or whatever part you have to get comment
$this->topics[$page]['topic']['question']['comment'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($thema->question->comment);
```

This should work the way you expect. But that is very dangerous. When you allow data to contain html unencoded parts you are open to [xss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755323/what-is-cross-site-scripting)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured it out because of you. But I did it by using the viewhelpers f:format.htmlentitiesDecode method. Now the HTML tags are recognized as HTML instead of plain text.