# Trying to add a link following a text in XML

Tags: html, xml, web

I am trying to include a hyperlink in XML that follows a text I wrote

My code is as follows:

```
<PROPERTY name="google" value="This is a Sample description that explains how to connect to google to go to google simply" date="10/22/2021 22:05"/>
```

What I want to do is to add the word 'CLICK_HERE' after the word simply and when the user clicks on it it takes them to https://google.com

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: XML is unlike HTML; you can make up whatever elements/attributes you wish, so a hyperlink implementation is up to you. Who is reading the XML? If it is just your own code then you may modify it to make use of CDATA https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412418/12989672 If not, are they expecting entity-escaped HTML or plain text data? You may not have an option in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! It is not me who is viewing the content, I simplified the code so I can post it in here. I am trying to add the hyperlink to the text .  Thank you again

Comment: I agree that xml is unlike html I am sure it is just a simply line to add after the word simply this is what I am trying to figure out